# Transition will not apply to height when browser resizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

When I resize the browser and the width goes either below 1001px or above 1000px, I want the nav's height to gradually change. Instead, it snaps to the new height. Any ideas?

```
nav.cust-navbar {
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;           
}


@media(max-width:1000px) {

    nav.cust-navbar {
        height: 94px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the navbar's height, because the initial value is auto.
Try to give it a fixed or percentage height so it can transition between them.

ex:

```
nav.cust-navbar {
    height: 300px;// or height: 20%
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;           
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Only two media queries are written for navbar in bootstrap.

1)One for less than 767px.

2)The other for min-width: 768px;

In the second media query which is for min-width: 768px, there the CSS for navbar's height is set to auto !important because navbar-right is floated to the right hand side of the navbar and when we decrease the size of the browser the navbar-right which is floated to the right comes down automatically and therefore, eventually the height of the navbar snaps.
So if you want that transition should take place then mention the height some x height of it because auto will result in no change of transition effect.

Comment: Who said he was using bootstrap? the question was about css transition issue.

Comment: Because in bootstrap navbar , the heights snaps at 991px.
You only had mentioned that the height is set to auto.
Then from where did you get height auto?

Comment: The problem was I did not set the initial height. Apparently you can't use the default height and it needs a specific set height for it to animate.